# Can't find eclipse.ini within RAD installation

Tags: rad

I am getting JVM Teriminated , Exit code =1 when i try to open RAD 6.0 installed on Windows 7 - 64 bit. Upon looking for resolution of the problem i found that resolution of this lies somewhere within eclipse.ini file. I can't find eclipse.ini within my installation directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no eclipse.ini in RAD. RAD has rationalsdp.ini within RAD Home Directory.